# About a sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics

I need to calculate the following sum: $\sum_{k=0}^{[\frac{n}{2}]}$ $n\choose 2k$ $\frac{1}{4^{2k}}$.
I guess it has to do something with identity $\sum_{k=0}^{n}$ $n \choose 2k $ $=2^{n-1}$, but I am not sure should I use some substitution for counter of this sum or I am on wrong way?

Comment: Do you know the binomial theorem proof of $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom n{2k} = 2^{n-1}$? And have you tried adapting it?

Comment: If $$u_n=\sum_{2k\leqslant n}\binom{n}{2k}\frac{1}{4^{2k}}$$ and $$v_n=\sum_{2k+1\leqslant n}\binom{n}{2k+1}\frac{1}{4^{2k+1}}$$ then $\displaystyle u_n+v_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\ldots=\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^n$ and $\displaystyle u_n-v_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\ldots=\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n$ thus $u_n=\frac{(u_n+v_n)+(u_n-v_n)}{2}=\frac{5^n+3^n}{2^{2n+1}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\sum_{k \ge 0} a_{2k} = \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{1+(-1)^k}{2} a_k.$$
Taking $a_k = \binom{n}{k}/4^k$ yields
\begin{align}
\sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{n}{2k}\frac{1}{4^{2k}} 
&= \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{1+(-1)^k}{2} \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{4^k} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{n}{k} \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^k
+ \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{n}{k} \left(\frac{-1}{4}\right)^k \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left(1+\frac{1}{4}\right)^n
+ \frac{1}{2} \left(1-\frac{1}{4}\right)^n \\
&= \frac{(5/4)^n+(3/4)^n}{2} \\
&= \frac{5^n+3^n}{2^{2n+1}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Let $$ u_n=\sum_{0\leqslant 2k\leqslant n}\binom{n}{2k}\frac{1}{4^{2k}} $$
and $$ v_n=\sum_{0\leqslant 2k+1\leqslant n}\binom{n}{2k+1}\frac{1}{4^{2k+1}} $$
then
$$ u_n+v_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{4^k}=\left(1+\frac{1}{4}\right)^n=\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^n $$
because adding the odd and the even terms of the sum gives the whole sum, and
$$ u_n-v_n=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{4^k}=\left(1-\frac{1}{4}\right)^n=\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n $$
by the same argument, noticing that $(-1)^k=1$ if $k$ is even and $(-1)^k=-1$ if $k$ is odd. Thus $u_n=\frac{(u_n+v_n)+(u_n-v_n)}{2}=\frac{5^n+3^n}{2^{2n+1}}$.

Comment: I just have one question, in the first answer we are computing this as we have $\sum_{k=0}^{n}$ but in the original sum I have $\sum_{k=0}^{[\frac{n}{2}]}$. Does that makes difference or I am missing something?

Comment: $2k\leqslant n\iff k\leqslant\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor$, in fact your original sum is the sum of the even terms in $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Compute, using the binomial theorem $$\frac{(x+1)^n+(1-x)^n}{2}.$$

For your particular question, you can not use that one because both are a particular case.